# What do I use instead of init_put_byte in a ffmpeg program?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to fix a program, and one issue is the use of the deprecated init_put_byte (avio.h). But there's no documentation saying what do I change it for. Where can I find anything about it?

[This page](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2011-February/104675.html) shows the function being substituted by `avio_init_context`, but my version have only the `init_put_byte` (deprecated).

My version (as in "/usr/local/include/libavformat/version.h") is:

```
#define LIBAVFORMAT_VERSION_MAJOR 52
#define LIBAVFORMAT_VERSION_MINOR 103
#define LIBAVFORMAT_VERSION_MICRO  0
```

**--update**

I did a `grep -R "_init_context" /usr/local/include/libavformat/*"`, but I found nothing. There's no function with this suffix.

Answer (score 2):

you need to replace init_put_bytes with ffio_init_context().

ffio_init_context - initializes AVIOContext
init_put_bytes    - initialized ByteIOContext

ByteIOContext is replaced by AVIOContext in newer version.

Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Comment: There's no `ffio_init_context` in my "avio.h". Maybe I should post my "avio.h" file here (it's 678 lines)? The only other function with "init" in the name is the "init_checksum".

Comment: how did you installed this version ? which flavor of linux (ubuntu/fedora/redhat)?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10, I got a vmware from the development team here, but I believe it was installed the default way (with apt-get), but it was some time ago.

Comment: i would suggest to take the latest ffmpeg and compile it ffmpeg yourself. the lates version definitely has ffio_init_context(), and you would be able better control version mismatch in future.

Comment: It's something we're looking forward to, but thanks for the help!